# Where are all the prize bubbles in the Act 1 stage of the LittleBigPlanet Metal Gear Solid level pack?

Tags: little-big-planet

I have been through Act 1 of the *Metal Gear Solid* level back countless times and can't find all the prize bubbles.  Where are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This youtube video could probably help you :

Comment: So it looks like all the black figures that pop out as you move through the level are sticker triggers.  As you trigger each one, you'll get prize bubbles.